# Generic type variable cannot be resolved in subclass

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

I am trying to extend this abstract class.

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class FilteredIterator<E1, E2> implements Iterator<E1>
{
  protected Iterator<E1> baseIterator;
  protected List<E2> filterValue;

  public FilteredIterator( Iterator<E1> baseIterator, List<E2> filterValue )
  {
    this.baseIterator = baseIterator;
    this.filterValue = filterValue;
  }
}
```

.
.
.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FilteredIteratorImpl extends FilteredIterator<E1, E2>{

  public FilteredIteratorImpl(){
     super();
  }
```

When I do this, I get the error messages 'E1 cannot resolve to a type', 'E2 cannot resolve to a type', and 'The constructor FilteredIterator(Iterator, List) refers to the missing type E1'.

I have tried replacing E1 and E1 with actual parameters in the extend line, in the super constructor, and in the FilteredIteratorImpl constructor. I have also tried declaring these variables in FilteredIteratorImpl for E1 and E2, even though I'm pretty sure I don't need to do that, since they are declared in the abstract method. Can anyone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type parameters are scoped to the declaring class (or method). In other words, `FilteredIteratorImpl` doesn't have access to type parameters declared in `FilteredIterator`.

If you mean for `FilteredIteratorImpl` to be generic, you'll need to declare it as such

```
class FilteredIteratorImpl<E1, E2> extends FilteredIterator<E1, E2> {
```

and provide an appropriate constructor.

If it's not meant to be generic, you'll need to specify type arguments in the `extends` clause

```
class FilteredIteratorImpl extends FilteredIterator<String, Integer> { // or whatever
```